# Can't install nginx with passenger after ubuntu server 12.04 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to install nginx with passenger support on 12.04

I've used [the brightbox](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/nginx-passenger-3-ubuntu-packages) repo before but that doesn't work now.

I've also tried ppa:nginx/stable but when I try to run `sudo apt-get install nginx-passenger` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.0.14-1ppa1~precise) but 1.2.0-1ppa1~precise is to be installed
                   Depends: ruby-passenger (> 3.0.11debian) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The last part about the holds seems invalid, `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`:

```
netatalk                    hold
```

And searching for `nginx` shows them listed as `deinstall`.

How on earth do I fix this?

Comment: I'd say get rid of the installed PPAs, run `apt-get update`, then try; PPAs aren't necessarily stable, and something's broken about the requirements of the PPA package that it's trying to install.

Comment: Sure, that works but the ubuntu version of nginx doesn't have passenger support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screw it, I went with the default nginx and used thin with a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. In the end it turned out that my apt sources were not correct, and a

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/passenger-nginx; 
>   sudo apt-get update;
>   sudo apt-get upgrade

did the trick.